# Angular CSS Animation won't work

Tags: css, angularjs, css-transitions

I have a system in place that retrieves dynamically retrieves stored messages from the server, the view for it is:

```
<div id= "messages" data-ng-controller="MessageController">
    <div class="message" data-ng-repeat="message in messages | orderBy:'timestamp':true" data-ng-animate="'animate-message'" >
            <div class="user">
                {{ message.user.username }}
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                {{ message.title }}
            </div>
            <div class="content" data-ng-bind-html-unsafe="message.content">
                {{ message.content }}
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I then have in my CSS file:

```
.animate-message-enter {
    transition: 1s linear all;
    -moz-transition: 1s linear all;
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all;
    -o-transition: 1s linear all;
    -ms-transition: 1s linear all;
    opacity:0;
    position:relative;
    left:-100%;
}

.animate-message-enter.animate-message-enter-active {
    opacity:1;
    left:0%;
}
```

(this is just an extreme example transition so I can see the transition working)

However, upon a new object being entered into the array via `$scope.messages.push(response);` the new message simply pops onto the page and no animations take place, does anyone know what I've messed up?

Thanks :)

Comment: the syntax for transition shorthand should be `all 1s linear` if i remember correctly. Try fixing that and let me if it works.

Comment: No change. Still the same instant pop in. Thanks anyway though :)

Comment: css looks fine. could be your orderBy - take it out and see what happens.

Comment: Ahh.. seems I hadn't updated the file that loaded angular to use the latest version instead of the stable version which didn't have the animations. However now I'm only occasionally getting animations appearing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to copy paste your code into plnkr and it works fine. Do you have more code?

http://plnkr.co/edit/gi6h3adNMfoXkUdiN4lY

The only thing I added was a simple addMessage function to test the transition.

```
<button ng-click="addMessage()">Add Message</button>
```

Comment: Odd, for me only sometimes does the item on that page transition in.. On Firefox 22.0 / Windows 7

Comment: I tried Firefox and got the same problem (was using Chrome Canary before)

Comment: Well thank you anyway, proved the error was my fault. Working fine on my site now in chrome. :D